# How to highlight text in a JTextPane with setFocusable(false)?

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jtextpane, focusable

So I have a `JTextPane` that basically serves as a console. I have it in the center field of a `JFrame` and a `JTextField` in the south field. The `JTextField` will take the text it has, and add it to the `JTextPane` when the user presses enter. In order to make the `JTextPane` not editable by the user I had to `setFocusable(false)`, because using `setEditable(false)` stopped any text from appearing on the `JTextPane`. But while I don't want the user to edit the pane, I would still like the user to be able to highlight text in the pane, but I can't seem to find a way to do this.

Below is a sample demonstrating what I mean

**Sample**

```
package resources;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

public class SampeTextPane extends JFrame
{
    public SampeTextPane()
    {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane display = new JTextPane();
        display.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        display.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        display.setFocusable(false);
        appendToPane(display, "Example", Color.BLUE);

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                appendToPane(display, field.getText(), Color.BLACK);
                field.setText("");
            }
        });

        add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void appendToPane(JTextPane pane, String text, Color color)
    {
        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground, color);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

        int len = pane.getDocument().getLength();
        pane.setCaretPosition(len);
        pane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        pane.replaceSelection(text + "\n");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        new SampeTextPane();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> using setEditable(false) stopped any text from appearing on the JTextPane.

You can make the `JTextPane` uneditable but you can't update the text via the text pane.

Instead you can update the text via the `Document`:

```
//int len = pane.getDocument().getLength();
//pane.setCaretPosition(len);
//pane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
//pane.replaceSelection(text + "\n");

try
{
    StyledDocument doc = pane.getStyledDocument();
    doc.insertString(doc.getLength(), text, aset);
}
catch(BadLocationException e) { System.out.println(e); }
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option, albeit more convoluted, is to use a boolean flag to allow or disallow changes to the document, something suggested StanislavL [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12702623/522444).

In your situation, it could look something like:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.text.AttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument;
import javax.swing.text.DocumentFilter;
import javax.swing.text.SimpleAttributeSet;
import javax.swing.text.StyleConstants;
import javax.swing.text.StyleContext;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SampeTextPane extends JFrame {
    private boolean isApi = false;

    public SampeTextPane() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(350, 200));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JTextPane display = new JTextPane();

        ((DefaultStyledDocument) display.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocFilter());

        display.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        display.setMargin(new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5));
        // !! display.setFocusable(false);
        appendToPane(display, "Example", Color.BLUE);

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                appendToPane(display, field.getText(), Color.BLACK);
                field.setText("");
            }
        });

        add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(field, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private void appendToPane(JTextPane pane, String text, Color color) {
        isApi = true;

        StyleContext sc = StyleContext.getDefaultStyleContext();
        AttributeSet aset = sc.addAttribute(SimpleAttributeSet.EMPTY, StyleConstants.Foreground,
                color);

        aset = sc.addAttribute(aset, StyleConstants.Alignment, StyleConstants.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);
        int len = pane.getDocument().getLength();

        String selection = pane.getSelectedText();
        if (selection == null) {
            pane.setCaretPosition(len);
            text += "\n";
        }        
        pane.setCharacterAttributes(aset, false);
        pane.replaceSelection(text);

        isApi = false;
    }

    private class DocFilter extends DocumentFilter {
        @Override
        public void insertString(FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (isApi) {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void remove(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
            if (isApi) {
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void replace(FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs)
                throws BadLocationException {
            if (isApi) {
                super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new SampeTextPane());
    }

}
```

Comment: Interesting way of going about it, and from what I can see it does about the same thing, but it slightly exceeds my Java knowledge. Thanks though!

Comment: @Ryan: yes, Camickr's suggestion is **much** cleaner, and I'm glad that you went with that. I was creating my code before he posted his correct answer, and so I hated to not post my "efforts". I did up-vote his answer, of course.